# Caffe Autoencoder

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I wanna compare the performance of CNN and autoencoder in caffe. I'm completely familiar with cnn in caffe but I wanna is the autoencoder also has deploy.prototxt file ? is there any differences in using this two models rather than the architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it also has a deploy.prototxt.

both `train_val.prototxt` and 'deploy.prototxt' are cnn architecture description files. The sole difference between them is, `train_val.prototxt` takes training data and loss as input/output, but 'deploy.prototxt' takes testing image as input, and predicted value as out put.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So the question is in aouto-conder case the network would predict the image! right? the output would be s.th like matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a cnn and autoencoder for MINST: [Caffe Examples](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/mnist). (I have not tried the examples.) Using the models is generally the same. Learning rates etc. depend on the model.

Comment: Yes I read it but it is still not clear to me! I did regression with cnn but the output of the network was predicted label. But I don't know what the out put of implementing regression on auto-encoder would be!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an auto-encoder example using python or matlab. The example in Caffe is not true auto-encoder because it doesn't set layer-wise training stage and during training stage, it doesn't fix W{L->L+1} = W{L+1->L+2}^T. It is easily to find a 1D auto-encoder in github, but 2D auto-encoder may be hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the Auto encoders and conventional network is

1. In Auto encoder your input is your label image for training.
2. Auto encoder tries to approximate the output similar as input.
3. Auto encoders does not have softmax layer while training.
4. It can be used as a pre-trained model for your network which converge faster comparing to other pre-trained models. It is because your network has already extracted the features for your data.
5. The Conventional training and testing you can perform on pre trained auto encoder network for faster convergence and accuracy.